# Problems with Imagick and PHP

Tags: php, imagick

My PHP script that uses Imagick gives me this error when I run it:

> Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/script.php on line 320

If I run `php` from SSH it gives me this warning:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/modules/imagick.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/imagick.so: undefined symbol:
>   php_checkuid_ex in Unknown on line 0

The weird thing is that Imagick is always worked... I've tried to install it but it says that everything is already installed.

The lib is in the correct place:

```
# locate imagick.so
/usr/lib/php/modules/imagick.so
```

I've tried switching to the beta version of imagick because seems that Imagick has problems with the PHP version 5.4.2 but the problem is not solved:

```
pear config-set preferred_state beta
pecl upgrade imagick
```

When I try to upgrade it was failing on the configuration:

> error: Unable to find MagickWand.h or magick-wand.h header ERROR:
>   `/var/tmp/imagick/configure --with-imagick' failed

So I've created a symlink of `magick-wand.h` to `/usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h` but now the errors is on the make:

```
/var/tmp/imagick/imagick_helpers.c:859: error: 'PaletteBilevelMatteType' undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/tmp/imagick/imagick_helpers.c:859: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/var/tmp/imagick/imagick_helpers.c:859: error: for each function it appears in.)
make: *** [imagick_helpers.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I've solved this problem.

I've removed ImageMagick and ImageMagick-devel

```
yum remove ImageMagick
yum remove ImageMagick-devel
```

Then I've installed a more recent version from RPM:

```
cd /root
wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/linux/CentOS/i386/ImageMagick-6.8.7-6.i386.rpm
wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/linux/CentOS/i386/ImageMagick-devel-6.8.7-6.i386.rpm
rpm -Uvh ImageMagick-6.8.7-6.i386.rpm
rpm -Uvh --nodeps ImageMagick-devel-6.8.7-6.i386.rpm
```

*note the --nodeps, needed because it was looking for a ImageMagick-libs that I can't find and seems not needed*

then I've uninstalled Imagick

```
pecl uninstall imagick
```

And I've compiled it again using pecl

```
pecl install imagick
```

Everything is worked (with some warning but it works correctly after the installation).

This solution works on CentOS 5/6 x86, look for the libraries for your arch or distro if you have a different OS.

Answer (score 7):

I solved my issue with an uninstall then a re-install of 'imagick' extension using the pecl command

SSH into server as Root and type

```
pecl uninstall imagick
```

then...

```
pecl install imagick
```

Please note this is on a Centos 6.5 and running php 5.4.42 and ImageMagick 6.7.2-7

Worked a treat